# How to Fix "GetChildText(string element name, string namespace)" while parsing RSS Feed?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing, rss

I am working on a project which is going to parse the iTunes RSS Feed.

I used XML Service - documentation provided [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) - and it seems pretty easy until I came across elements of iTunes namespace. The method to parse XML elements along with their namespaces is, as provided by Google :

```
getChildText(name, namespace)
```

Where both the name and namespace parameters are in string. So following the documentation and examples provided, I tried this code:

```
function customScraperRSSFeed() {
 var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:279094703/sounds.rss').getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
var ituneEntries = document.getRootElement().getChildText('email', 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
Logger.log(ituneEntries);
}
```

But somehow, If I run this code, I get the following error:

> Cannot find method getChildText(string,string)

I know there are other methods including `getChild(name,namespace)` which follows the same path.

Here are the tags with iTunes namespace that I want to parse:

[image: tags screenshot].

And here is the link to complete RSS Feed: `http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:279094703/sounds.rss`

Now, I want to know if there is something wrong with the code that I am doing? I have tried all the variations and I even tried this:

```
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:279094703/sounds.rss').getContentText();
 var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
 var ituneEntries = document.getRootElement().getChildren('channel');
 for(var i=0; i<ituneEntries.length; i++)
    {
      var name = ituneEntries[i].getName();
      if(name=='subtitle')
      {
        Logger.log(ituneEntries[i].getText());
      }
      else if(name=='owner')
      {
        var ownerInformation = ituneEntries[i].getChildren();
        Logger.log(ownerInformation[0].getText());
        Logger.log(ownerInformation[1].getText());
      }
    }
```

As far as the above code is concerned, I had a plan to loop over all the elements by required tag names and then getting their values and even then, I was getting NULL values for some tags.

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the result values you want?

Comment: I do want all the results - tag values - that are of iTunes namespace. So that simply means any tag starting something like this: <itunes:Tag Name>

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about ``I do want all the results - tag values - that are of iTunes namespace.``. For example, when there are ``<itunes:Tag Name>sample value</itunes:Tag Name>``, which do you want to retrieve the value of ``sample value`` or ``Tag Name`` or other value?

Comment: It should get the sample value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve all values when the prefix of namespace is `itunes`.
- For example, when there are `<itunes:Tag Name>sample value</itunes:Tag Name>`, you want to retrieve `sample value`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could confirm like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:279094703/sounds.rss').getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var c = document.getRootElement().getChild('channel').getChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i].getName() == 'item') {
      var item = c[i].getChildren();
      for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
        if (item[j].getNamespace().getPrefix() == 'itunes') {
          Logger.log("%s, %s", item[j].getName(), item[j].getValue())
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [XML Service Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/)